# How to Use Quick Notes Using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, nsuseractivity

I am trying to implement Quick Notes through SwiftUI, rather than UIKit or AppKit.  I am unsure if the behaviour below is due to a bug or if there is something I am missing.

I have already successfully implemented NSUserActivity for Handoff, Spotlight and Siri Reminders, using the `.userActivity()` view modifier.  These NSUserActivity instances use the `NSUserActivity.userInfo` dictionary to store and correctly restore the content through the `.onContinueUserActivity(perform: )` methods.

Quick Notes requires using the `.persistentIdentifier` or `.targetContentIdentifier` properties, rather than the `.userInfo` dictionary alone.  However, when I set these either of these to unique identifiers using the code below, they are not correctly stored within the useractivity.

```
MyView()
    .userActivity(ActivityString, updateUserActivity)

private func updateUserActivity(_ activity: NSUserActivity) {
    activity.isEligibleForSearch = true
    activity.isEligibleForHandoff = true
    activity.title = "Title"

    activity.targetContentIdentifier = myItemUniqueID
    activity.persistentIdentifier = myItemUniqueID
    activity.userInfo = ["id": myItemUniqueID]

    print(activity.targetContentIdentifier) // Correctly prints
    print(activity.persistentIdentifier) // Correctly prints
    print(activity.userInfo) // Correctly prints
    }
```

The identifiers print correctly when setting the user activity above.  However, when restoring the user activity (tested through Handoff and Spotlight Search), the targetContentIdentifier and persistentIdentifier strings are empty.

```
MyView()
    .onContinueUserActivity(ActivityString, perform: continueUserActivity)

private func continueUserActivity(_ activity: NSUserActivity) {

    print(activity.persistentIdentifier) // Nil
    print(activity.targetContentIdentifier) // Nil
    print(activity.userInfo) // Correctly prints
    }
```

Is there something else I must do, or is this unexpected behaviour?